# Jquery : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code below and when i try to run get the error when i call the function . I wonder hey this his happening ? help plz ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //load config file 
        $.getScript(baseURl+"/wsj/wconf.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            console.log(data); // it is ok 

                jq();  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
                //_cusApp.ini();  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ini' of undefined 

                var _cusApp = {
                        ini: function (inc) {
                            console.log('ini'); 
                        },
                };

                var jq = function ( ){
                    $(document).height(); // jquery not availble here   
                }
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: I think there are confliction with other jQuery. Please check this

Answer (score 6):

It's about invoking `jq()` function before it's declared.

`jq` is undefined, because it's not declared yet...!

### Update (@David Barker suggestion)

The whole code would work if a named function would be declared instead of an anonymous one.

As an anonymous function is created during run-time, it's not available until the assignment is executed.

In opposite, as a named function is declared in *parse* time, it's available to the code even if it's declared after invoking it.

#### Example of anonymous function

```
myFunction(); // Wrong, it's undefined!

var myFunction = function() {};

myFunction(); // OK, now is declared and it can be invoked
```

#### Example of named function

```
myFunction(); // As the function has been already parsed, it is available!

function myFunction() {};

myFunction(); // OK!
```

Comment: maybe some clarification on why `var jq = function() {...}` and `function jq() {...}` differ would give the op some clarity? +1 though as this is the answer.

Comment: @Blender Sometimes a downvote isn't the best option. I thought I was right and that's why I updated the question. I've removed the whole update because you're right. Keep calm!

Comment: @Blender Why you removed your comment?!

Comment: @MatiaFidemraizer spot on :-)

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //load config file 
    $.getScript(baseURl+"/wsj/wconf.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data); // it is ok 

        //these two variable declaration shoule happen before their usage
        var _cusApp = {
            ini: function (inc) {
                console.log('ini'); 
            },
        };

        var jq = function ( ){
            $(document).height(); // jquery not availble here   
        }

        jq();
        _cusApp.ini();
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Unless he's running in `strict` `jq` should be hoisted, so I don't see what this fixes.

Comment: @AndréDion no, a function expression will no get hoisted, declaration will get hoisted

Comment: @AndréDion see function expression error http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YPQMt/1/ and declaration http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YPQMt/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan mostly by AndréDion from his comment

Comment: @AndréDion http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html would be a good read

Comment: I didn't downvote you, sorry. I removed my answer and upvoted your comment correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

First you declare a function and then call her because javascript read line by line one after the other, when you call the function jq () it still had not been declared ..

'sorry for my english'